# How to Removing XML node using SED or Unix shell script command

Tags: unix, sed

I have a sample xml file like below,

```
<Students>
    <student>
        <name>john</name>
        <id>123</id>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>mike</name>
        <id>234</id>
    </student>
</Students>
```

I wanted to remove one particular student node by using the name. For example i would like to remove the student john element

```
<student>
        <name>john</name>
        <id>123</id>
</student>
```

from the xml file. How can I achieve this in shell script or SED.

Am looking for shell script command rather using xmlstarlet. How to archive the same using SED with REGEX.

Please advise.

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmlstartlet as below;

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "/Students/student[name='john']" 11
```

`ed` is to edit or update XML.

`-d` is to delete param.

`"/Students/student[name='john']"` is xpath

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ xmlstarlet ed -d "/Students/student[name='john']" 11
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Students>
  <student>
    <name>mike</name>
    <id>234</id>
  </student>
</Students>
```

Comment: Am looking for shell script command rather using xmlstarlet. How to archive the same using SED with REGEX.